# Nightwatch using expect in url callback, result.value is undefined

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm messing around with Nightwatch and I have a test setup like the following:

```
module.exports = {
    'Load index page with default category' : function(browser)
    {
        browser
            .url(browser.launch_url)
            .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
            .url((result)=>
            {
                console.log(result.value) // http://example.com/something/
                browser.expect.result.value.to.contain("something");
                // TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined
            })
            .end();
    }
}
```

I'm confused how I'm supposed to use result.value with expect.
`result.value` logs as expected, but I can't verify it.
I *can* use `browser.assert.urlContains("something")`, but I was trying to use `expect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chai library directly but PASS will not be in report while FAIL will be shown.

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/601